# Is there a way to combine two aggregate functions in MySQL to get distinct values?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following schema in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `ORDER_CONTENTS` (
  `Order_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Pizza_Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Quantity` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Order_ID`,`Pizza_Name`),
  KEY `ordercontentsfk2_idx` (`Pizza_Name`),
  CONSTRAINT `order_contentsfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`Order_ID`) REFERENCES `ORDERS` (`Order_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `CUSTOMERS` (
  `Mobile_Number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Age` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gender` enum('M','F') DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Mobile_Number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Mobile_Number_UNIQUE` (`Mobile_Number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `ORDERS` (
  `Order_ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Mobile_Number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Postcode` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `Timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Order_ID`),
  KEY `ordersfk1_idx` (`Mobile_Number`),
  KEY `ordersfk2_idx` (`Postcode`),
  CONSTRAINT `ordersfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`Mobile_Number`) REFERENCES `CUSTOMERS` (`Mobile_Number`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `ordersfk2` FOREIGN KEY (`Postcode`) REFERENCES `STORES` (`Postcode`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `STORES` (
  `Postcode` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone_Number` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Postcode`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Postcode_UNIQUE` (`Postcode`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Address_UNIQUE` (`Address`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Phone_Number_UNIQUE` (`Phone_Number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need to find the following:

**Problem Statement**

> **For each customer, list the store details of their favorite pizza
>   store, where a store is the favorite if it is the one where the
>   customer purchased the most pizzas).**

I have managed to figure it out upto the following query:

```
select `Name`,SUM(quantity) as hqty,COUNT(*),Postcode from CUSTOMERS natural join orders natural join order_contents group by Mobile_Number,postcode;
```

This gives me a result as the following:

```
+---------------+------+----------+----------+
| Name          | hqty | COUNT(*) | Postcode |
+---------------+------+----------+----------+
| Homer Simpson |   19 |        3 |     4000 |
| Homer Simpson |    1 |        1 |     4502 |
| Ned Flanders  |    2 |        1 |     4000 |
+---------------+------+----------+----------+
```

But in this case there are two instances of the same customer ( i.e. Homer Simpson). Why is this so? I figured that I would need to use a combination of aggregate function.

Any help/explanation would be great.

Cheers!

**[UPDATE 1]**
Just for reference:

> select * from CUSTOMERS natural join orders natural join
>   order_contents;

The above query produces this:

```
+----------+---------------+---------------+------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
| Order_ID | Mobile_Number | Name          | Age  | Gender | Email           | Postcode | Timestamp           | Pizza_Name   | Quantity |
+----------+---------------+---------------+------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
|        1 | 0412345678    | Homer Simpson |   38 | M      | homer@doh.com   |     4000 | 2014-08-21 19:38:01 | Garlic Bread |        9 |
|        1 | 0412345678    | Homer Simpson |   38 | M      | homer@doh.com   |     4000 | 2014-08-21 19:38:01 | Hawaiian     |        9 |
|        2 | 0412345678    | Homer Simpson |   38 | M      | homer@doh.com   |     4000 | 2014-08-21 19:38:01 | Vegan Lovers |        1 |
|        3 | 0412345678    | Homer Simpson |   38 | M      | homer@doh.com   |     4502 | 2014-08-21 19:38:12 | Meat Lovers  |        1 |
|        4 | 0412345679    | Ned Flanders  |   60 | M      | ned@vatican.net |     4000 | 2014-08-21 19:39:09 | Meat Lovers  |        2 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
```

Also *please note the problem statement*

Comment: Your customer  have two post code ... and your query group by the post code .. this is your problem

Comment: That's the point of the question... Please read the problem statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    customers c
JOIN    stores s
ON      s.postcode =
        (
        SELECT  postcode
        FROM    orders o
        JOIN    order_contents oc
        USING   (order_id)
        WHERE   o.mobile_number = c.mobile_number
        GROUP BY
                postcode
        ORDER BY
                SUM(quantity) DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

This won't show customers who have made no orders at all. If you need those, change the `JOIN` to `stores` to a `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Group by your customers primary key (maybe an ID).

The reason you are getting duplicate customers is because you are grouping the query by mobile_number and postcode, which isn't making a unique index.

Your query should become something like this:

`select Name ,SUM(quantity) as hqty,COUNT(*),Postcode from CUSTOMERS natural join orders natural join order_contents group by CUSTOMERS.id`

Replace ID with whatever the customers table PK is and it should group by the customer uniquely.

Comment: the mobile_number is the primary key for the CUSTOMER table :\

Comment: Try grouping by the phone number then

Comment: Oh and put a `MAX()` function on the sum to get only the route with the highest quantity (most pizzas ordered). Should be `MAX(SUM(quantity)) as hqty`.

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow MAX(SUM()) to be combined for some reason.